# Assigning a new value to a Tensor's weight and saving back to the model

Tags: python, tensorflow, assign

In `TF v1.3`, I can restore my model's meta and the weights using `tf.train.import_meta_graph` and `restore(sess,tf.train.latest_checkpoint`. Running `sess.run()` will give me the values of a tensor.

My question is how am I gonna be able to assign (re-write) new value to a tensor's value and save it back in the model for further processing. Say, I have these values for a given layer:

```
>>>(sess.run('MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/weights:0'))
...
1.55560642e-01,   1.29789323e-01,   2.59163193e-02,
8.00046027e-02,   4.73752208e-02,  -5.41094005e-01,
-8.93476382e-02,  -9.48717445e-02]]]], dtype=float32)
```

How can I use [tf.assign()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign) to assign different values to these last 8 printed values and save it back to my checkpoints.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe sth. like this can work for you:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
tf.reset_default_graph()


with tf.variable_scope('scope1') as scope:
    w = tf.get_variable('w', shape=[4,4])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
    np_w = sess.run(w)
    print(np_w)
    np_w[2:,2:] = np.ones((2,2))
    print("  .  '"*10)
    print(np_w)
    print("  .  '"*10)
    with tf.variable_scope(scope, reuse=True):
        v=tf.get_variable('w')
        sess.run(tf.assign(w, np_w))
    print(sess.run(w))
```

As an example I created a random *4x4* matrix with `get_variable` and reassigned a submatrix to *ones*. Hope this helps.

**EDIT**

For accessing the variable *w* from your saved model and then assigning a subset of it a new value:

```
w = [v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) if v.name == 'w:0'][0]
```

Now you can continue hacking *w* as I recommended above. *w* should have the same name as your variable in the restored model, e.g. `MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/weights`.

Comment: Thanks @prometu. Yes, this will work if you initialize the graph yourself. I would like to know how to assign new values to an already available pretrained model (like MobileNet) and save it back on a certain tf.Tensor's value.

Comment: I assumed that you have already done it. Check my edited answer :)

Comment: Thanks a lot, @prometeu. So, your edited answer will assign a new value to a subset of variable w. Does it mean that it is saved to the model simultaneously? or I have to execute sess.run('w') for that matter?

Comment: Lets say that there is a model that you have restored. This model has a _graph_ and a set of trained variables, e.g. {w1, b1, w2, b2, ..., wn, bn}. If you want to fine tune, lets say  _w2_, you can get it with 'w2 = [v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) if v.name == 'w2:0'][0]`. So now you can process _w2_ as you wish, for example you can convert it in np.array and change the last eight elements and than assign the processed numpy array back to the _w2_. Next step is to save  back the variables. Now you have an unchanged _graph_ and trained variables with fine-tuning.

Comment: After modifying a variable you allways have to save them if you want to use them later. But this is another theme. I'll try later to edit my answer again.

Comment: so `[v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) if v.name == 'MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/weights:0'][0] is giving me the  interested tensor` as `<tf.Variable 'MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/weights:0' shape=(3, 3, 3, 32) dtype=float32_ref>` which I saved in an array, say, `w=sess.run()`. I change some values inside my w and then save it back with `with tf.variable_scope(scope, reuse=True):
        v=tf.get_variable('w')
        sess.run(tf.assign(w, np_w))
    print(sess.run(w))` given that I have to use its previous name `'MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/weights:0'` rather than `w`. Am I understood?

Comment: After you change some values to _w_, you assign it back to your variable with `sess.run(tf.assign([v for v in tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES) if v.name == 'MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/weights:0'][0], w)` and then you save all the variables.

Comment: I see. let me try and report back real quick.

Comment: Try to put everything together and see if it works. If not open another question on stackoverflow describing the problem that you will have with some code. Because this is already another question (how to get variables, how to save them, names/scopes). And of course somebody else can  recommend a better solution. I'm also new to tensorflow :)

Comment: Apparently, everything went well and it did save on it since running `sess.run('MobilenetV1/Conv2d_0/weights:0')` shows the updated values, The last part in the puzzle would be to save it back to the pre-trained model which I used to retrieve. Could you tell me that as well? :D Having this I can edit my question, so people can see the whole process 0-100% at once.

Comment: This part is trickier for me. I would suggest to save all the variables for example with `saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.GLOBAL_VARIABLES))`, not sure though.

Comment: Thanks a lot, @prometeu. Yes. making the `saver` object and then `saver.save(sess, 'my_model',global_step=X)` saved the new variable. Cheers buddy. appreciate your help.

Comment: With pleasure! I will update my answer with all the stuff in the comments someday. Cheers!

Comment: Came back to check your answer again and was wondering if we can do the same with the `tf.Const` that are in a frozen.pb file. In general how can we assign new values to those tensors? Thanks!